# SocketChannel: interrupt close all open channels

Tags: java, socketchannel

I have the following scenario:

- A server open's a ServerSocketChannel and accept client connections.
- Every connection (socketA) is handled in a new thread.
- Inside the thread I open a new SocketChannel (socketB) which connects a another server.
- The original client connection (socketA) is idle at this time.
- The new SocketChannel reads data (blocking) from the server.

Now I interrupt the thread. I expected that socketB will be interrupted and closed and socketA will be continue to work. Unfortunately socketA will also be interrupted.

Any idea what could be the problem?

I use the following test methods to reproduce the behavior:

```
private void testServerSocket() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    final InetSocketAddress     address         = new InetSocketAddress( "localhost", 12345 );
    final ServerSocketChannel   serverChannel   = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.socket().bind( address );

    final SocketChannel socketChannel   = serverChannel.accept();

    // start communication in new thread
    final Thread    thread  = new Thread( new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { testWrite( socketChannel ); } } );

    thread.start();

    // wait a little bit
    Thread.sleep( 5000 );

    // interrupt thread, will interrupt the socketChannel.read in testRead()
    thread.interrupt();
    thread.join();

    socketChannel.close();
    serverChannel.close();
}

void testWrite( SocketChannel socketA )
{
    try
    {
        // write to client
        socketA.write( ByteBuffer.wrap( "0123456789".getBytes() ) );

        // open new socket to another server
        testRead();

        // throws ClosedByInterruptException
        socketA.write( ByteBuffer.wrap( "0123456789".getBytes() ) );
    }
    catch( final IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void testRead()
{
    try
    {
        final InetSocketAddress address   = new InetSocketAddress( "localhost", 12346 );
        final SocketChannel     socketB   = SocketChannel.open( address );

        // server doesn't send, so this call will block and interrupted 
        socketB.read( ByteBuffer.wrap( new byte[10] ) );

        socketB.close();
    }
    catch( final IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the thread's interrupted state by calling `Thread.interrupted()` after the `IOException` in `testRead()`. Actually you should catch `ClosedByInterruptException` and do it there. Otherwise the condition persists and interrupts the write as well.

Comment: But this couldn't be the general solution for the problem. If I replace the SocketChannel code in testRead with a simple Thread.sleep( 20000 ), socketA will not be interrupted.

Comment: And in real life, i have no simple testRead and testWrite functions. For example in my server the testRead function is not from me but a CORBA function from the java runtime.

Comment: @user1909432 The real solution is to not interrupt threads but  close the socket and have the thread exit itself on that condition.

Comment: How should I do that? The testRead method in the example is in real life a CORBA call that can hang several minutes without timeout. How should I realize a timeout handling without interrupts? As far as I know SocketChannel implements the InterruptibleChannel interface exactly for that reason.